# How do I turn off a 12V 3A RGB LED strip?

Tags: power, voltage-level, rgb-led

I'm trying to understand how to control an RGB LED strip, I set up all the `TIP120` (because I could get my hands on an n-channel mosfet), if I power everything in this way I can change colours and everything:
[image]

but now I'm facing a dilemma now, whats the correct way to manage to switch my power strip ON/OFF based on an input from a pir sensor? I mean, how can I handle 12V 3A (requested by my led strip), how do I correctly wire my Arduino up in order to make it switch the LED strip ON/OFF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty simple: when you turn off all the colours you are actually turning off the entire strip with very minimum leakage current in each of the three FETs.

Comment: Oh...really? Is that so simple? Do I need to use some king of Voltage regulator? Is it safe for my Arduino to receive a 12V in(yes) at 3A(I don't know)? The schema provided so will be ok? I don't even need to put 12V into my Arduino..right?

Comment: @FabioEnne With the schematic you have provided the 12V doesn't go anywhere near the Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko I know...I was just wondering if with this schematic will I be able to switch the LED strip off

Comment: @FabioEnne The FETs (or TIP-120s if you must) are just switches. Just like a light switch. Only for dimming you switch the light switch on and off really really fast.

Comment: @Majenko so you mean that I just need to give to the Red, Blue and Green pin a zero value or just set them to LOW?

Comment: That is correct. 0 is off. All three channels at 0 the entire strip is off.

Comment: @Majenko so in this way I should need any sort of voltage regulator right?

Comment: @FabioEnne You only need a voltage regulator when you want to change a voltage from a higher one to a lower one for the purposes of powering a device.